# Jsx build a table and limiting items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to build this table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>more...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My array have more than 4 items, like

```
[{name:1},{name:2},{name:3},{name:4},{name:5},{name:6}]
```

I've done with the limiting part

```
items.map((obj, i) => {
    if(i < 3) {
        return(<span>{obj.name}</span>)
    } else if(i === 4) {
        return(<span>more...</span>)
    }
})
```

But because of the name might be not the same I have to turn div or span tag into table.

Comment: Can you give more sample data/code? I'm confused on what you're looking to do

Comment: @BenHare How to construct table with array of object with these 2 requirement 1) it should be in a table like above 2) limit the array length and replace 4th item with 'more...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build it explicitly? Not sure what you are looking for, but there is no need to make it more complicated than it is:

```
var table =
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{items[0].name}</td>
        <td>{items[1].name}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{items[2].name}</td>
        <td>More...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
;
```

Comment: won't work this way, I have to wrap a tooltip for the `More...` thus I need a loop (map).

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the tooltip supposed to show?

Comment: the rest of the item? like item 4,5,6,7.. so i have to use items[i].name

Comment: For the forth item and above? Like `4,5,6`? If so, what does that have to do with generating the rest of the table? And why didn't you mention that in your question? You can generate the "more" cell however you want: `<td><Tooltip text={items.slice(4).map(x => x.name).join()}>More...</Tooltip></td>` . I don't see how that would change how you create the other cells.

Comment: so you suggest I don't continue my loop? hmm make sense, it make me easier to create the table.

Comment: Yep! As I said, keep it simple :) a loop is useful if you have to perform the same operation for every element. In your case though, having to split up things into rows makes things more complicated. Since you only want to show three items, hardcoding them seems to be the easier solution.